# "Directory(s)", "director(ies)"...: what's the correct parenthetical plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, orthography, suffixes, parenthetical-plural

Often times "(s)" is added to the end of a word to represent one or more of something:

> "He saved the file(s)."

What do you do when the plural of the word is not created by simply adding an "s?"  Take the word "directory" for example:

> "He copied the directory(s)."

That's clearly wrong...

> "He copied the director(ies)."

...also clearly wrong.

***What do I do with a word like this?***

Comment: I've seen the former, but never the latter. Maybe _directory(ies)_?

Comment: Or director(y/ies)? haha this is a strange one...